# Error message when Selecting Replication | Distribution Configuration

Tags: replication, sql-server-2019, failover-cluster-instance

We have a SQL Server 19 installation configured for Failover Cluster Instance.  I have been asked to setup replication between two databases on this server.  When following the Microsoft documentation to prepare the server for replication, the part in SMSS where I right click on Replication and select ‘Distribution Configuration..’  gives me these error messages:

> SQL Server is unable to connect to server 'XXXXXX98'. (Configure
> Distribution Wizard)

And

> SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a
> connection to the server. Specify the actual server name, ''.
> (Replication.Utilities)

I get the same message from both the listener for the FCI, and from the active node.

Comment: When connected to the Distributor server, if you run [`SELECT @@SERVERNAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/servername-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), does the server name shown in the results match the server name SSMS shows in the Object Explorer? Is your SQL Server instance a named instance?

Comment: Hi J.D.    I am new to the term named instance, and I didn't install the instance, but after some Googling, I think it is not a named instance and the default was used when it was installed.  SELECT @@SERVERNAME returns the name of the Failover Cluster Instance listener, rather than the name of the active node.    The good news is that for some reason when connected to SMSS from the inactive node I was able to run the Distribution Configuration wizard and have now moved on to other problems.     Thanx so much for your post!   Heather

Comment: No problem, glad you got past this stopping point. Yea I've recently learned myself that Replication in SSMS requires you to connect to the exact server name (no CNAMES instead etc), otherwise you run into the error you were hitting.